# Verwendung von "nicht mehr" und "nicht länger"

Tags: word-usage, anglicism

Im Deutschen scheint seit geraumer Zeit die Redewendung "nicht länger" vermehrt an Stellen benutzt zu werden, an denen ich "nicht mehr" sagen würde.

Eines von vielen aktuellen Beispielen ist der Buchtitel [Warum ich nicht länger mit Weißen über Hautfarbe spreche](https://www.bpb.de/shop/buecher/schriftenreihe/300304/warum-ich-nicht-laenger-mit-weissen-ueber-hautfarbe-spreche). Das Phänomen ist aber nicht ganz neu, beispielweise gibt es einen Film mit Titel [Du darfst nicht länger schweigen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_darfst_nicht_l%C3%A4nger_schweigen) aus dem Jahr 1955.

Natürlich gibt es auch Verwendungen wie in "Ich will nicht länger warten", die ich für angemessen halte.

Ich habe den Verdacht, dass die vermehrte Verwendung von "nicht länger" durch Übersetzungen aus dem Englischen populär geworden ist (im Englischen wird häufig "no longer" oder "not any longer" gesagt).

Handelt es sich also hier um eine Art Anglizismus oder trügt mein Sprachgefühl?

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the German, but to my American ears the phrase "no longer" seems a bit dated, formal and/or British. I'd use "-n't anymore", as in "I won't wait anymore," at least in everyday speech. So if you want to blame English for this, please blame *the* English and leave us Americans out of it. I have the feeling that Dee Snider's career would have gone differently with the lyric went "We'll no longer take it" instead of "We're not gonna take it anymore."

Comment: @RDBury If I am right that there is as an inappropriate use of "nicht länger", and if  this should be a sort of Anglicism (which doesn't seem to be sure), then nobody else than we Germans deserve to be blamed ;-)

Comment: In einigen Zusammensetzungen ist "nicht länger" sehr gebräuchlich und für mich auch eleganter. 
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&case_insensitive=true&smoothing=3&content=nicht+l%C3%A4nger+dulden%2Cnicht+mehr+dulden&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnicht%20l%C3%A4nger%20dulden%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnicht%20mehr%20dulden%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnicht%20l%C3%A4nger%20dulden%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnicht%20mehr%20dulden%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=31&smoothing=3&content=nicht+l%C3%A4nger+schweigen%2Cnicht+mehr+schweigen&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnicht%20l%C3%A4nger%20schweigen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnicht%20mehr%20schweigen%3B%2Cc0#

Comment: @CarstenS Wäre das nicht eine offzielle Antwort wert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es dürfte sehr schwer sein, die vielen Gründe, die parallel dazu führen, dass bestimmte Redewendungen populärer werden, zutreffend zu analysieren.

Kann gut sein, dass das Englische eine Rolle spielt. Kann sein, dass "nicht länger" in einer bestimmten Zielgruppe ab einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt als weniger langweilig und "fresher" als das schnöde "nicht mehr" wahrgenommen wird. Kann aber auch sein, dass der leicht andere Sinn ausdrücklich gewünscht ist, zum Beispiel will der Verlag, der sich für den deutschen Buchtitel "Warum ich nicht länger mit Weißen über Hautfarbe spreche" entschieden hat, vielleicht damit tatsächlich betonen, dass die Autorin bisher eben nicht nur irgendwann mal mit Weißen über Hautfarbe gesprochen hat, sondern fortwährend und ununterbrochen.

Mir ist es für "nicht länger" auch aufgefallen, mich erinnert es auch an frühere Beispiele, in denen bestimmte Wendungen plötzlich en vogue waren. Wennn man den "Spiegel" über längere Zeit gelesen hat, weiß man, dass dort eigentlich schon immer neue Wendungen und Anglizismen aktiv benutzt wurden, um die Sprache frischer und progressiver klingen zu lassen, während zum Beispiel die FAZ sich eher sprachkonservativ gibt.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort (+1). Das zitierte Buch hat übrigens den englischen Oiginaltitel "Why I'm No Longer Talking to White People About Race". Nun ein Zitat aus der Inhaltsangabe aus meinerm Link: *Für die britische Autorin Reni Eddo-Lodge steht daher fest: Mit "Weißen" will sie **nicht mehr** über Hautfarbe sprechen, zumindest nicht mit denjenigen, die ihr ihre Erfahrungen mit Rassismus und Diskriminierung absprechen wollen.*

Comment: Übrigens fiel mir die m.E. unpassende Verwendung "nicht länger" erstmalig in Übersetzungen von englischen SF-Texten aus den 1950-er bis 1960-er Jahren auf. Gut möglich, dass die Übersetzer nicht gerade Meister ihres Faches waren.